# How to factor numbers like 8,023 manually

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factoring, prime-factorization

I was given a random 4-digit number to factor over the prime numbers. My number was 8,023. I tried applying all the divisibility rules up to 36 before giving up on them. I tried using algebra as follows
$$8023=(10a+9)(10b+7),\space a>3,\space b>2$$
or $$8023=(10a+3)(10b+1),\space a>3,\space b>3$$
but this was very tedious and inefficient for the time limit. It was not feasible to apply brute force manually to both equations. I could not find a way to narrow down a or b within the time limit.
I ended it thinking it was prime, but
$$8023=71*113$$
Is there a method to efficiently factor *smaller* numbers with obscure factors such as 8023?

Comment: Not particularly. The fact that prime factorization is hard is somewhat of the entire point of it being a core component of many encryption  algorithms. Maybe a special trick will help you in this narrow instance, but probably not in general even for "small" numbers

Comment: Fermat's factorization by difference of squares ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/98476/242) or [WikiP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method)) takes only $3$ steps $\,a=90,91,\color{#c00}{92}.\ \ $

Comment: Once you have ruled out small factors by divisibility tests you can shift to a different approach.  Here you know that $8023$ is a semiprime as it is less than $31^3$.  Depending on the source of the problem it might well indicate that Fermat is the way to go.  For contest math I might even assume there are no small factors and go straight to Fermat.

Comment: @BillDubuque That only works well if n is product of primes close together.

Comment: 3 mod 4 have an odd number of 3 mod 4 factors. Either one shows up below 20 here or it has exactly 1.  It has remainder 1 on division by 6 so must have an even number of 5 mod 6 factors (includes the possibility of none)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is tedious. If n is random, you’d check if n is 0 or 1 (neither prime nor composite), whether n is 2, 3, 5 (prime), divisible by 2, 3, 5 (check the last digit it the sum of digits) and then n < 49 is prime.

Since 7x11x13 = 1001, you check if n modulo 1001 is divisible by 7, 11, or 13, and then everything less than 289 is prime. At this point less than one in five composite numbers remain.

If n < 10,000 then trial division is likely fastest. Above that you can look at the pollard-rho method; if n has a prime factor p then pollard-rho will very likely find it in say 3 sqrt(p) steps and often in sqrt(n) steps, that would be 30 steps for n = 10,000 or 100 steps for n = 1,000,000 or 500 steps for n = 1 billion. The problem is it doesn’t work for primes, so if it takes too long to find a factor then you’d use likely a non-deterministic primality test.